# Rename "Popular" and "New arrivals" tabs in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to rename "Popular" and "New arrivals" tabs in the home page of Prestashop. When I searched I found a solution like edit translation and edit those two words from it. But I can't find these words. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: There isn't a code cuz we deal with prestashop through user interface so if i want to change some label names i should do that through admin panel but i didn't know how to make that

Comment: This isn't "show me stack", it's stack overflow, which is code based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to Translations > `Installed modules translations`, select your theme, your language.

[image: Installed modules translations.]

Then make a trick to see all words – press `Close all fieldsets` and `Enable all fieldsets` again.

[image]
[image]

Now you should be able to find words "Popular" and "New arrivals" with a simple your browser search function.